# Notifications with sensitivity to the NotificationManager.Policy settings

Tags: android, android-notifications

Android developers. I need your help.It's for api>=23 with turn on "Do not dsturb".
I need to create notifications with sensitivity to the NotificationManager.Policy settings, but can't find a way.
We cant value without allowed permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

from these fields :

NotificationManager.Policy: priorityCategories, priorityCallSenders, priorityMessageSenders.

I think filter should work automatically in NotifiactionManager when we send notification with additional value as  priorityCategories.Value, priorityCallSenders.Value, priorityMessageSenders.Value.

How I can do It ? Will it work otherwise? Help me, please.

p.s. Now I think it values don't manage notifications, only calls and messages. Am I right?